# More than 1 group by statements in one query using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do 2 group by and sum statements in one query.
Am working on a project with Visual Studio MVC.

This is, what I managed to do so far:

```
var query = from sn in db.Standardtouren
                    from stid in db.Tagestouren
                    from d in db.Lieferscheine
                    from k in db.Fahrer
                    from stlid in db.StandardtourBestehtAusLieferadresse

                    where stid.VorlageStandardtour.Equals(sn.StandardtourID)
                    where k.FahrerID.Equals(stid.Fahrer)
                    where d.Lieferadresse.Equals(stlid.LieferadresseID)

                    group d by new {d.Lieferadresse, d.Deckungsbeitrag}
into d1
```

my aim is to have a table with the rows Tourname, Costs and Deckungsbeitrag, while Deckungsbeitrag is saved as (the sum of Deckungsbeitrag from the Lieferschein table) - (sum of kilometers from the table Tagestour  multiplied with costs from the table Fahrer).
So I first need 2 group by statemts where I build the sum and then I want to make a select Deckungsbeitrag as (the arithmetic function)
Ho can I do this?
Would be happy to get some help, as I am becoming crazy :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: Oh sry, can you still help?

Comment: It might help you get a better answer if you would translate the table/column names into English. Additionally, you seem to know what you want the resulting SQL to be, it would also help if you give an indication in code of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the result that you have on d1 is an IGrouping so you need to do something like this:

```
select new{ X1 = d1.Key.Lieferadresse.Sum(), X2 = d1.Key.Deckungsbeitrag.Sum() }
```

Also I would recommend to translate the example to English

Answer (score 0):

ok, its a logistic tool.
we have the tabel delivery order, where the marginal return of a certain tour is saved and several adresses, for example one delivery order can contain many adresses and these adresses all have an id but can belong to a certain tour, for example adress 1, 2, 3 belong to tour1, adress 4, 5, 6 to tour 2 and so on..
we have a table called tour, where theses tours are saved and also the costs of a tour, how long it goes (time) and we have a table driver, where the driver id is saved and also how much he gets paid for each hour.
now my aim is to calculate, whether the marginal return of a tour is enough to compensate the variable costs.
my formula is: marginal return - costs - (time*drivers earning/hour)
and then, I want to build a group by statement, where all the results which belong to a certain tour are summed up.
at the end I want to have something like this: tour1 200000$, tour2 150000$ and so on...
I hope you guys have understood it :D

Answer (score 0):

this is what I managed so far:

```
  var query = from sn in db.Tours
                    from d in db.deliveryorder
                    from l in db.adresses
                    from k in db.driver
                    from stlid in db.tourContainsAdresses


                    where k.driversID.Equals(stlid.driver)
                    where d.adresses.Equals(l.adresses)
                    select new {
                       sn.Name,
                       calculus= d.mgreturn-sn.costs-(sn.time*k.driverscost)
```

this is where I now have my problem, I want to build a sum of calculus where it is grouped by sn. name and calculus...